# How to addClass to list element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

I have been looking for an answer to this for a while and I thought that my code was correct but it doesn't seem to be working.

HTML

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<div class="navigation" align="center">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li id="aboutlink">About</li></a>
        <a href="#linkedin"><li id="linkedinlink">Linkedin</li></a>
        <a href="#contact"><li id="contactlink">Contact</li></a>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navigation a {
text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation  {
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
}
.navigation ul li {
color: #f0f0f0;
display: inline;
padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
}
.navigation ul li:hover {
border-bottom: solid 2px #cc4926;
}
.active {
border-bottom: solid 2px #007f59;
}

.body {
font-size: 16px;
}
```

jQuery 1.11.1

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#linkedinlink").click(function() {
     $(this).addClass('active')
   });
}),
```

You can also check out the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9no05urs/)

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, an `<a>` is not a valid child of a `<ul>`.

Comment: Was just a typo delete the last coma http://jsfiddle.net/9no05urs/3/

Comment: you have an extra comma at the end of your js. that broke the script. check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9no05urs/4/

Comment: The issue David pointed out prevents the list from displaying at all in Firefox. Also, you'll want to handle the other list items like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j86y4ct8/1/

Comment: Oh my god, that was probably the simplest mistake, thank you guys. I definitely got confused in the full code. This was just a snippet and my console throws all kinds of errors because it doesn't recognize jQuery. Thanks for the quick reply too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last `)` has a comma instead of a `;` which is causing it to throw an error, fix that and you should be golden.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhershman/9no05urs/2/

Edit: Keep an eye on your console. It is your guide to all things error.

Comment: Thank you this fixed everything...It was a stupid mistake. I'll be sure to look at my console more often. Do you know a good plugin for Brackets that supports jQuery error catching?

Comment: What kind of editor are you using?

Comment: Ohh, no I'm not familiar with that one sorry, I use sublime text 3 which has a very large plugin assortment to choose from.

Comment: I'll have to check that out. I like Brackets because it supports specific Adobe Plugins for mobile coding. Thanks again for pointing the error out!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="js/app.js"></script> <div class="navigation" align="center"> 
<ul>
<li id="aboutlink"> <a href="#">About</a></li> <li id="linkedinlink"> <a href="#linkedin">Linkedin</a></li> 
<li id="contactlink"> <a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> </ul> </div>
```

Firstly correct your HTML elements now try your jquery method on it.

$(document).ready(function() { $("#linkedinlink").click(function(e) e.prevent default(); $(this).addClass('active') }); }),

Comment: @Devash: Did that work for you?

Comment: Yes i m 100% sure.. But you need to add e.preventDefault() on click event.

Comment: @Devansh your html switches up his format drastically, OP is using a horizontal navbar style, this html does not work properly, nor does it fix his issue of creating a class "active". Please look a his fiddle and try your attempt there and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: On sec i will post some thing which help you wait for a moment...

Comment: @Devansh: http://jsfiddle.net/gq5ogkd2/ is the fiddle the OP gave with your HTML. It doesn't work. Oh, and I didn't include your added javascript since it isn't working javascript. Perhaps you should get it working on jsfiddle and then once you've done that copy the code directly. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Devasnsh_Kumar/gmt1j5aL/2/